# What would be better with POJO object list

Tags: android, serialization, jackson, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a JSON structured as follows:

```
 {
  "bag" : {
    "descrition" : "my bag 1",
    "text" : 123456,
    "item" : {
      "-K5D9mi--s6jPWNwrNEu" : {
        "name" : "name item",
        "value" : 60
      },
      "-K5R3ugcTVFnNlAEAHus" : {
        "name" : "name item 2",
        "value" : 55
      }}}
 }
```

If I make my POJO class as below:

```
    public class Item {
        String name;
        int value;
   }
   public class Bag {
      String descrition;
      String text;
      List<Item> item;
    }
```

When I deserialize the object with the code below gives error, referring to the object list "item":**"JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token"**

```
 Firebase ref = new Firebase("myAdressFirebase/bag/");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Bag bag = dataSnapshot.getValue(Bag.class);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
```

What would be the best POJO to json up to me regain the parent object Firebase and their children in a single call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not serialize a object/hash map structure in a List of Items. There is no place for the keys e.g `"-K5D9mi--s6jPWNwrNEu"` or `"-K5R3ugcTVFnNlAEAHus"` ;-).

It's been a long time since I had used Jackson but I'm fairly sure that you can use a `Map<String, Item>` as type for the `item`-attribute in your class `Bag`. i.e. I expect that Jackson provides a converter from JSON Object to the Java Map<> interface and vice versa.

Comment: Peter! Thank you! is just that, replacing the List for a HashMap. Like this: "HashMap <String, Item> Item" on Bag class. To retrieve the values of the HashMap do so: 
for (Map.Entry <String, Item> entry:. Bag.getItem () entrySet ()) {
   Item item = entry.getValue ();

Comment: Ahhhh sorry, I forgot to format the `Map<String, Item>` text as code. I fixed it for my answer. Thank you for your comment.